# force a specific .net version during compilation

Tags: .net, compilation, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, aif

My Dynamics AX 2009 application has a button 'Generate' to compile AIF services and create a dll.

The DLL should be generated with version 2.0.50727. But of late it is being generated with version 4.0.30319.

It is in our control to change the web.config file.

However, I'm not clear which tags to use to force the compilation with 2.0.50727.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We found a solution to this issue

The AOS server’s ax32Serv.exe.config file located in “C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\50\Server\yourInstance\Bin” had the following entry

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
</startup>
```

Temporarily commenting this out and generating the service produced the DLL with 2.0.50727 CLR version.